# How to allow OpenLDAP user to write data to SSHFS mount point?

Tags: permissions, sshfs, openldap, write

I mounted a network drive (Storage Server) to the directory `/home/ldap` for all OpenLDAP client computers. If a user login one of the computers, their home directory will be set the mount point as: `/home/ldap/users/{username}`. Users can read and write to their directory freely.

Now I have a tester account in OpenLDAP named `tester4` under group `users` and logged into one of the computers. After login, I run `ls -al` to check the permissions.

```
Location: tester4@Computer1:/home/ldap/users/tester4

$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x 1 tester4 users     4096 Aug 30 20:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    usrstomgr 4096 Aug 30 18:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 tester4 users      220 Aug 30 17:57 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 tester4 users     3771 Aug 30 17:57 .bashrc
drwx------ 1 tester4 users     4096 Aug 30 17:57 .cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 tester4 users      655 Aug 30 17:57 .profile
```

I tried to create a directory in this directory but not successful. `tester4` is the owner of the directory, why `tester4` does not have the write permission?

```
Location: tester4@Computer1:/home/ldap/users/tester4

$ mkdir no
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘no’: Permission denied
```

Then, I directly use `tester4` to login the storage server and create a directory.

```
Location: tester4@Storage:/home/ldap/users/tester4

$ mkdir no
$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x 2 tester4 users     4096 Aug 30 23:02 no
```

What is the problem disallowing `tester4` to write to the SSHFS mount point? The following is the commands (without sudo) I used to mount the network drive in Computer1, where `casper` is the admin user of Computer1.

```
sshfs -o allow_other -o kernel_cache -o auto_cache -o cache=no -o reconnect -o compression=no -o cache_timeout=6000 -o ServerAliveInterval=15 casper@{Storage IP}:/home/ldap /home/ldap
```

#### Update

If I change the owner of `.` directory to `casper`, `tester4` can write to the directory. If `tester4` create a file, the owner of the file is `casper`.
How can I configure SSHFS to allow other users to write to the directory using their identity?

Comment: I doubt that this setup will work. You mount that `ssfs` with a specific user, in your case `casper`, and all file creations/modifications/deletes will be executed on the storage server with the user ID which has initiated the mount. So you either should mount the user home for each user ( maybe possible with autofs ), or why not use NFS?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to mounting. If I use NFS, can I use `root` to mount the network folder and all other users can access the content under the basic Linux permission rules?

Comment: Basically yes. But the storage server should also be integrated to the LDAP server to do user and group name lookups.

Comment: `autofs` seems easier than `NFS`.

Comment: NFS is easier to setup and maintain. You also would have to integrate the storage server to your LDAP server as the users need to login to the storage server to do a `sshfs` mount. And performance will be much better with NFS. Go for NFS.

Comment: The `integrate` means properly create and setup POSIX groups and accounts in OpenLDAP tree?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44696/discussion-between-thomas-and-casper-li).